# Is there something I am doing wrong that makes my Keras model.fit to keep throwing errors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True, input_length = TO_BE_FOUND))

model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_size, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['acc'])
```

Here is my fit model:

```
model.fit(train_x_padded, train_y_padded,batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=2,shuffle=True, validation_data=(train_x_padded, train_y_padded)
```

Here is the error i have been getting:

```
AlreadyExistsError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-24-109d4dab5962> in <module>() ----> 1 model.fit(train_x_padded, train_y_padded,batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=2,shuffle=True, validation_data=(train_x_padded, train_y_padded))
 .
 .
 .
 AlreadyExistsError: Resource __per_step_26/training_6/RMSprop/gradients/lstm_5/while/ReadVariableOp_4/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var/N10tensorflow19TemporaryVariableOp6TmpVarE
[[{{node training_6/RMSprop/gradients/lstm_5/while/ReadVariableOp_4/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var}}]]
```

Comment: If you get unexpected errors from Keras, it is always advisable to uninstall it and then again install it

Answer (score 0):

Try clear_session from [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/#clear_session):

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

> Destroys the current TF graph and creates a new one. Useful to avoid clutter from old models / layers.